# My first cypress e2e test fails to do much of anything; an obvious failure is not reported

Tags: authorization, cypress

I am new to Cypress trying to run an e2e test. My modest goal is to create an account and login with that account. My expected result is that I get some indication that the line I highlight with a comment `// should fail!` reports a failure. My actual result is that I don't get much of anything!

Error message: none! kind of.

I get some messages about failed post requests, does this matter? See the red "POST 400". Does that interrupt my tests?

[image]

Here's my test:

```js
    it("registers, logs in, and waits for the refresh token to refresh", async () => {
        cy.visit(baseFrontendUrl);
        const loginResponse = await axios.post(baseBackendUrl + "/auth/email/login", { email: "rm" });
        const accessToken = loginResponse.data.accessToken;
        console.log(accessToken, "access token");
        const allUsersResponse = await axios.get(baseBackendUrl + "/auth/all", {
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
        });
        const allUsers: Member[] = allUsersResponse.data;
        console.log(allUsers, "24rm");
        const allTestAccounts = allUsers.map((m: Member) => m.googleId.slice(0, 4) === "TEST");
        const nextTestAccountFieldValue = "TEST" + (allTestAccounts.length + 1).toString();
        const nextTestAccount = {
            email: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
            firstName: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
            lastName: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
            fakeGoogleId: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
        };
        cy.get("#devPortal").should("have.text", "SHOULD OBVIOUSLY FAIL"); // doesn't fail!

        cy.get("#signUpEmail").type(nextTestAccount.email);
        cy.get("#signUpFirstName").type(nextTestAccount.firstName);
        cy.get("#signUpLastName").type(nextTestAccount.lastName);
        cy.get("#signUpGoogleId").type(nextTestAccount.fakeGoogleId);
        cy.get("#signUpButton").click();
        // assert
        cy.get("#msg").should("have.text", "Successful registration").should("be.visible"); // doesn't seem to run at all
    }
```

Neither of the requests in the above code fail; they work fine and I know that because the `accessToken` value logs something.

Putting `expect(true).to.equal(false)` does show `assertexpected true to equal **false** AssertionError` and "true to be true" does give `assertexpected true to equal **true**` so perhaps I don't understand `should`?

And in case its not clear, the text for `#devPortal# is not "should obviously fail"! :-)` Sign up with email: `

I don't know what to look for because I am newb at Cypress. It's something obvious, I'm sure.

edit: So I disabled the bunch of axios requests at the top. The tests worked after that: [image]

edit2: This solution isn't perfect because I want to (a) get the list of users => (b) get the # of test accounts => (c) increment the # at the end of "testAccount" by 1 so the e2e test runs with a new account. I need to login, get an access token, and hit an endpoint, for this to work. *Hence the question becomes, "why does running an axios request at the start of the test make it malfunction?"*

Answer (score 3):

The axios calls are succeeding, but they aren't part of the test they just set up some "fixture" data for the sign-in test itself.

I would separate that block of code out to make things more understandable.

Usually you will make API calls using `cy.request()` rather than axios, and
then you don't need `async/await` which are in fact **"illegal"** in Cypress (the commands don't return promises so you can't await them).

```js
beforeEach(() => {

  cy.request('POST', baseBackendUrl + "/auth/email/login", { email: "rm" })
    .then(response => {
      const accessToken = response.data.accessToken;

      cy.request(baseBackendUrl + "/auth/all", {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
      })
      .then(response => {
        const allUsers: Member[] = response.data;

        const allTestAccounts = allUsers.map((m: Member) => m.googleId.slice(0, 4) === "TEST");

        const nextTestAccountFieldValue = "TEST" + (allTestAccounts.length + 1).toString();
        const nextTestAccount = {
          email: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
          firstName: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
          lastName: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
          fakeGoogleId: nextTestAccountFieldValue,
        };
        cy.wrap(nextTestAccount).as('nextAccount') // use alias to save value 
      })
    })
  })
})

// no need for async when using cy.request()

it("registers, logs in, and waits for the refresh token to refresh", () => {
  cy.get('@nextAccount').then(nextTestAccount => {
    cy.visit(baseFrontendUrl);
    ...
```

I think your problem with the `.should()` not failing the test may be due to the `async/await` around the test. Obviously the assert is failing as it's logging red, but if the test is still passing then it looks like a timing issue - the test is completing too soon.

Comment: I set it up so that just the email field `"rm"` will log the tests into the system... and I can see using console logs that the request succeeds. Those failed requests are reported from the website itself, not the Cypress suite; they're still there if I disable my bunch of axios requests made from the test suite.

Comment: I see what you're saying - the axios requests are just to figure out what the next signup email will be. The axios calls are working, and are unlikely to be causing the issue. You can substitute `cy.request()` but the net effect should be the same. You can also isolate that step in a `beforeEach()`, really just to make things tidier.